# Error: Apply not allowed for workspaces with a VCS connection

Tags: terraform, github-actions

```
Error: Apply not allowed for workspaces with a VCS connection
```

I am getting this error when trying to apply a terraform plan via Github Actions.

**Github Action (terraform apply)**

```
- name: Terraform Apply Dev
  id: apply_dev
  if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/master' && github.event_name == 'push'
  run: TF_WORKSPACE=dev terraform apply -auto-approve deployment/
```

**Terraform workspace**
The workspace was created on Terraform Cloud as a `Version control workflow` and is called `app-infra-dev`

**Terraform backend**

```
# The configuration for the `remote` backend.
terraform {
  backend "remote" {
    hostname = "app.terraform.io"
    organization = "my-org-name"
    workspaces {
      prefix = "app-infra-"
    }
  }
}
```

So because I called my workspace `app-infra-dev`, my workspace prefix in the backend file is `app-infra-` and `TF_WORKSPACE=dev` is set in my GH Action. I would have hoped that would have been enough to make it work.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

Your workspace type must be "**API driven workflow**".

https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/github-actions

I had the same issue because I initially created it as "**Version control workflow**", which makes sense, but it doesn't work as expected.

Extracted from the documentation:

> In the UI and VCS workflow, every workspace is associated with a
> specific branch of a VCS repo of Terraform configurations. Terraform
> Cloud registers webhooks with your VCS provider when you create a
> workspace, then automatically queues a Terraform run whenever new
> commits are merged to that branch of workspace's linked repository.

https://www.terraform.io/docs/cloud/run/ui.html#summary

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/master' && github.event_name == 'push'`, you might consider trigger the apply on the GitHub event itself, as [in this example](https://github.com/YukiTominaga/gcp-actions/blob/f2584782f677fbfedc01ba0c418f0d7be54ed652/.github/workflows/terraform-apply.yaml)

```yaml
name: terraform apply

# Controls when the action will run.
on:
  # Triggers the workflow on push or pull request events but only for the main branch
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
```

In that example, you can see the terraform apply used at the end of a terraform command sequence:

```yaml
# A workflow run is made up of one or more jobs that can run sequentially or in parallel
jobs:
  # This workflow contains a single job called "build"
  apply:
    # The type of runner that the job will run on
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    # Steps represent a sequence of tasks that will be executed as part of the job
    steps:
      # Checks-out your repository under $GITHUB_WORKSPACE, so your job can access it
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: hashicorp/setup-terraform@v1
        with:
          terraform_wrapper: true
          terraform_version: 0.14.0

      # Runs a single command using the runners shell
      - name: create credentials
        run: echo "$GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS" > credentials.json
        env:
          GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS: ${{ secrets.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS }}

      - name: export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
        run: |
          echo "GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=`pwd`/credentials.json" >> $GITHUB_ENV
      - name: terraform init
        run: terraform init

      - name: terraform workspace new
        run: terraform workspace new dev-tominaga
        continue-on-error: true

      - name: terraform workspace select
        run: terraform workspace select dev-tominaga
        continue-on-error: true

      - name: terraform init
        run: terraform init

      - name: terraform workspace show
        run: terraform workspace show

      - name: terraform apply
        id: apply
        run: terraform apply -auto-approve
```

Check if you can adapt that to your workflow.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried what you said and removed the if statements that I had and still hit the same issue when it comes to apply :(